# Import SMS/MMS on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sms, mms

I currently have an Android phone, and I recently ordered a BQ Aquaris 4.5 Ubuntu Touch Edition.
I wonder if there is a way to import SMS/MMS from my Android phone, to my BQ Aquaris 4.5...
I know we can import contacts, but I don't know about SMS and MMS.

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/#save-android-data

Comment: The article you sent me, tells you can backup your Android data, if you would like to reinstall Android later. But I want to backup my Android data, to import it on Ubuntu Touch, it's not the same. ;-)

Comment: Yes the backup can be restored through certain commands which I am not aware of. Hope some member may post instructions for restoring backup.

Answer (score 1):

All SMS are stored in `$HOME/.local/share/history-service/history.sqlite`.

So you can try (if you know well [sqlite](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/datamanipulation/)) to import all of it manually via SQLite (but, **before do anything, backup the sqlite file**, you might lose all of your sms is you do an mistake).

So an ability in SQL and XML is required to follow this "method".